# Reading large Files

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I want to read a 50MB file and send it over tcp. The file contains only floats. First I created only a Mainwindow, witch reads one line and sends it to the Server, but the gui got frozen. So I created a class that depends on QThread called QSendThread. Here is the Code for the class QThread:

```
#ifndef QSENDTHREAD_H
#define QSENDTHREAD_H

#include <QThread>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QFile>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QtNetwork/QTcpSocket>
#include <QtNetwork/QHostAddress>

class QSendThread : public QThread
{
 Q_OBJECT

public:
 QSendThread(QTcpSocket* qtcpso, QLabel* qlbl, QFile* qfiel, QObject *parent = NULL);
 ~QSendThread();

protected:
 void run(void);

private:
 QTcpSocket* qtcpsoDest;
 QLabel* qlblRef;
 QFile* qfileRef;

signals:
 void error(QString qstrError);
};

#endif // QSENDTHREAD_H

#include "qsendthread.h"

QSendThread::QSendThread(QTcpSocket* qtcpso, QLabel* qlbl, QFile* qfile, QObject *parent)
 : QThread(parent)
{
 qtcpsoDest = qtcpso;
 qlblRef = qlbl;
 qfileRef = qfile;
}

QSendThread::~QSendThread()
{
}

void QSendThread::run(void)
{
 int iLine = 0;

 do
 {
  QByteArray qbarrBlock;
  QDataStream qdstrmOut(&qbarrBlock, QIODevice::WriteOnly);

            // show witch line is read
  qlblRef->setText(tr("Reading Line: %1").arg(++iLine));

  qdstrmOut.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_6);
  qdstrmOut << (quint16)0;
  qdstrmOut << qfileRef->readLine().data();
  qdstrmOut.device()->seek(0);
  qdstrmOut << (quint16)(qbarrBlock.size() - sizeof(quint16));

  qtcpsoDest->write(qbarrBlock);
  qtcpsoDest->flush();

  qbarrBlock.clear();
 } while(!qfileRef->atEnd());
}
```

But the program crashing in the method `qregion::qt_region_strictContains(const QRegion &region, const QRect &rect)`

Is the method to read the file like I am doing wrong?

Thanks for Help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you shouldn't really need to subclass QThread. The Qt documentation is [misleading on this point](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/). See this [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213738/qthread-blocking-main-application/3213979#3213979) for a similar question for lots of good info.

Second, you can only correctly access the gui from the main thread so your call `qlblRef->setText()` would be a problem. Accessing the gui from a thread other than the main one can be done using [signals and slots](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) or [postEvent()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#postEvent). You can read up on events [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html).

Finally, this [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads.html) is really required reading for working with threads in Qt. Pay particular attention to the section on [threads and QObjects](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html).

**Addition:**

To follow the advice above, you could certainly wrap your file reading code in a `QObject` subclass. An alternative (which I have little experience with myself) may be to try putting your code in [QtConcurrent::run()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentrun.html) and getting the result with a [QFuture](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentrun.html#returning-values-from-the-function).

Comment: Okay, I should not create a class that inherits from QThread, but should I write a class to read the file? And is the method to read the file how i did right? Because it always takes so long to read the file and programs like notepad++ or kate do not need such a long time.