# Qt moveToThread() vs calling new thread when do we use each

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

When do we use each of this function calls in a threaded application.
given two functions fun1() and fun2() defined in the same class dealing with read/write of data into buffers(queue operation). to achieve multi-threading to these. we would have to run the two functions in a separate thread. now lets say the first function read is called at the start of its thread.

> is it better to use moveTothread ( second thread)for
>   function write at the start of the first
>   functions thread

Or

> define the second function in a new
>   thread class and call that thread at
>   the start of the first thread.

Comment: related: [QThread blocking main application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213738/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `moveToThread` we can change the thread affinity of an object. What the OP asks is how we can run two functions of the same class in different threads.

Let class `A` and two functions `f1` and `f2`

```
class A
{
public:
    void f1();
    void f2(int i); 
    void run(); // shows how we can trigger f1 and f2 in different threads
}
```

`Qt` already provided a class for running functions in different threads and it is called [`QtConcurrentRun`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentrun.html)

> The `QtConcurrent::run()` function runs a function in a separate thread.
>   The return value of the function is made available through the `QFuture`
>   API.

The function that is triggered can be either an external function or a member function. So in our case if we wanted from the object itself to start `f1` and `f2` in different threads we could do the following in `run()`

```
void run()
{
   // QFuture<void> because f1 is void 
   QFuture<void> future1 = QtConcurrent::run(this, &A::f1);
   int k = 5; // Concurrent run with arguments
   QFuture<void> future2 = QtConcurrent::run(this, &A::f2, k);
}
```

similarly you could execute any public function of any class concurrently, eg

```
QImage image = ...;
QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::run(image, &QImage::invertPixels, QImage::InvertRgba);

A a;
QFuture<void> future1 = QtConcurrent::run(A, &A::f1);
```

Notice the difference between the two calls:

> `QtConcurrent::run()` also accepts pointers to member functions. The
>   first argument must be either a const reference or a pointer to an
>   instance of the class. Passing by const reference is useful when
>   calling const member functions; passing by pointer is useful for
>   calling non-const member functions that modify the instance.

In order to check when a concurrently executed function has finished you should use a [`QFutureWatcher`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfuturewatcher.html).

Answer (score 9):

Like Piotr answered you should really have a look at the link he suggested.
As I understand your problem, that should solve your problem.
This is the simplified code from that blog:

```
class Producer  
{  
public:
    Producer();  

public slots:
    void produce()
    { //do whatever to retrieve the data
      //and then emit a produced signal with the data
      emit produced(data);
      //if no more data, emit a finished signal
      emit finished();
    }

signals:
    void produced(QByteArray *data);
    void finished();
};

class Consumer
{
public:
    Consumer();

public slots:
    void consume(QByteArray *data)
    {
       //process that data
       //when finished processing emit a consumed signal
       emit consumed();
       //if no data left in queue emit finished
       emit finished();
    }
};

int main(...)
{
    QCoreApplication app(...);

    Producer producer;
    Consumer consumer;

    producer.connect(&consumer, SIGNAL(consumed()), SLOT(produce()));
    consumer.connect(&producer, SIGNAL(produced(QByteArray *)), SLOT(consume(QByteArray *));

    QThread producerThread;
    QThread consumerThread;
    producer.moveToThread(&producerThread);
    consumer.moveToThread(&consumerThread);

    //when producer thread is started, start to produce
    producer.connect(&producerThread, SIGNAL(started()), SLOT(produce()));

    //when consumer and producer are finished, stop the threads
    consumerThread.connect(&consumer, SIGNAL(finished()), SLOT(quit()));
    producerThread.connect(&producer, SIGNAL(finished()), SLOT(quit()));

    producerThread.start();
    consumerThread.start();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: This was a perfect reference for the problem I was trying to solve. Nice idiomatic Qt approach.The only modification I made was to decouple the `consumed()` signal from the `produce()` slot and connect the producer's `finished()` signal with the consumer's `finished()` signal. This way the producer doesn't wait on the consumer, and notifies consumer when it is safe to quit.